# CSS height animating width error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I have is that on the animation of the `cookies warning div` i'm trying to just animate the height to do something like this:

[Cookies warning on bottom](http://demo.cookieconsent.silktide.com/?consenttype=implicit&onlyshowbanneronce=false&bannerPosition=bottom&hideallsitesbutton=false&tagPosition=bottom-right&style=dark&clear=0)

If you open my website, you can see the animation goes from `height 0` to `height 75px` **BUT it also animates from left to right also (width)**, why is it doing that?

I'm just animating the height not the left to right, or width property.

[image]

This is the CSS:

```
    #cookiesWarning {
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 35px #888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 35px #888;
        -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
        transition: all 1.5s ease;
        height: 0px;
        position: fixed!important;
        z-index: 99999998!important;
        left: 0!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #cookiesWarning.active {
        height: 75px;
    }
```

And the script:

```
$('#cookiesWarning').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bZcvM/

```
transition: height 1s;
```

will animate just the height.

You may use just pure CSS with a close button (always in pure CSS)

http://jsfiddle.net/bZcvM/2/

Comment: added a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would to set the height: 75px when then div is hidden and give it top: 100% instead of bottom: 0;

```
#cookiesWarning {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 35px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #888;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    height: 0px;
    position: fixed!important;
    z-index: 99999998!important;
    left: 0!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    top: 100%;
}

#cookiesWarning.active {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0
}
```

that way it will be hidden because it's outside the div